# Deleting a specific edge without affecting the face

Tags: modeling, edges

[image]

The white edge is the one I am trying to remove, but when I try doing so via delete > edges,
It deletes the whole yellow face with it.

How can I keep the yellow highlighted face and delete the white edge only?

Thanks always community

Comment: You can't delete this edge without creating another one. Hole in face can be handled by two faces in minimum.

Comment: ooh so maybe adding a vertex somewhere else to reposition that white edge would work

Comment: Try it  use knife tool (K)

Comment: Hey that is also a very useful one to help understanding! Using knife tool worked too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to bevel the right bottom edge of the selected orange face, but the white edge was causing the bevel to result in a crashed shape. I apologize for the lack of elaboration in the question

A side with a hole must consist of two faces.

So I solved this problem by using knife tool to add a vertex somewhere else far from the side I was trying to bevel.